# Dotmatrix Printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, printing

I want to print document to **dotmatrix printer** like Epson-Fx-2175
from my Silverlight application.

Is this possible with silverlight oob/wpf/web application and how?

Is there any alternative way? Can I achieve this directly from the web browser using report viewer?

Comment: any progress on this question ? I have similar requirement too and will be interested .